# Unexpected behaviour in JVM class loading (ClassNotFoundException before the class is really needed)

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I would need help trying to understand why this is happening to me:

Using **Java 1.8.0_131**, I have a class such as this:

```java
public class DynamicClassLoadingAppKO {

    /*
     * THIS VERSION DOES NOT WORK, A ClassNotFoundException IS THROWN BEFORE EVEN EXECUTING main()
     */


    // If this method received ChildClassFromLibTwo, everything would work OK!
    private static void showMessage(final ParentClassFromLibOne obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.message());
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Throwable {

        try {

            final ChildClassFromLibTwo obj = new ChildClassFromLibTwo();
            showMessage(obj);

        } catch (final Throwable ignored) {
            // ignored, we just wanted to use it if it was present
        }

        System.out.println("This should be displayed, but no :(");

    }

}
```

Two other classes are being used up there: `ParentClassFromLibOne` and `ChildClassFromLibTwo`. The latter extends from the former.

There are two external libraries involved:

- One library is called `libone` and contains the `ParentClassFromLibOne` class. The application includes this library in the classpath both for compiling and executing.
- A second library is called `libtwo` and contains the `ChildClassFromLibTwo` class. The application includes this library in the classpath for compiling, **but not for executing**.

As far as I understand, the Java runtime should try to load the `ChildClassFromLibTwo` (which is **not** in the classpath at runtime) at this line:

```java
final ChildClassFromLibTwo obj = new ChildClassFromLibTwo();
```

Given this class is not in the classpath, a `ClassNotFoundException` should be thrown, and given this line is inside a `try...catch (Throwable)`, the `System.out.println` line at the end should be executed anyway.

However, what I get is the `ClassNotFoundException` thrown when the `DynamicClassLoadingAppKO` itself is loaded, apparently **before the `main()` method is executed at all**, and therefore not caught by the `try...catch`.

What seems more strange to me is that this behaviour disappears and everything works as I would expect if I change the signature of the `showMessage()` method so that instead of receiving an argument of the *parent* class, it is directly of the *child* class:

```java
/*
 * THIS VERSION WORKS OK, BECAUSE showMessage RECEIVES THE CHILD CLASS AS A PARAMETER
 */
private static void showMessage(final ChildClassFromLibTwo obj) {
    System.out.println(obj.message());
}
```

How is this possible? What am I missing in the way class loading works?

For testing convenience, **I have created a GitHub repository replicating this behaviour** [1].

[1] https://github.com/danielfernandez/test-dynamic-class-loading/tree/20170504

Comment: before executing, you must be able to compile. if a class can't be found: it can't compile.

Comment: As stated above, the "not found" class is available in the classpath at compile time, but not at runtime.

Comment: If a class is present at compile time but not at runtime, you would get a `NoClassDefFoundError` instead of `ClassNotFoundException`. To achieve your move-on-if-absent effect, you don't want to reference the optional class statically, but instead reflectively, i.e. something like `Class.forName("ChildClassFromLibTwo").newInstance()`.

Comment: Not exactly. You get a `NoClassDefFoundError` which *cause* (i.e. nested or inner exception) is a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the details of why this happens are explained in this Spring Boot ticket [1] which I've been very lucky to be promptly pointed to by Andy Wilkinson. That was definitely a difficult one IMO.

Apparently, what happens in this case is that when the calling class itself is loaded, the verifier kicks in and sees that the `showMessage()` method receives an argument of type `ParentClassFromLibOne`. So far so good, and this would not provoke a `ClassNotFoundException` at this phase even if `ParentClassFromLibOne` was not in the classpath at runtime.

BUT apparently the verifier **also scans method code** and notes that there is a call in `main()` to that `showMessage()` method. A call that does not pass as an argument a `ParentClassFromLibOne`, but instead an object of a different class: `ChildClassFromLibTwo`.

So it is in this case that the verifier does try to load `ChildClassFromLibTwo` in order to be able to check if it really extends from `ParentClassFromLibOne`.

Interestingly **this wouldn't happen if `ParentClassFromLibOne` was an interface**, because interfaces are treated as `Object` for assignment.

Also, this does not happen if `showMessage(...)` directly asks for a `ChildClassFromLibTwo` as an argument because in such case the verifier does not need to load the child class to check it is compatible... with itself.

Daniel, I'm voting up your answer but I will not mark it as *accepted* because I consider it fails at explaining the real reason why this is happening at verify time (it's not the class in the signature of the method that's causing the `ClassNotFoundException`).

[1] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8181

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but your answer is indeed more complete and correct. Please accept my upvote :).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit more complicated than you think. When a class is loaded, all functions are verified. During the verify phase also all referenced classes are loaded, because they are needed to calculated the exact types that are on the stack at any given location in the bytecode.

If you want that lazy behaviour, you have to pass the -noverify option to Java, which will delay the loading of classes until the functions that reference them are executed the first time. But don't use `-noverify` for security reasons when you don't have full control over the classes that will be loaded into the JVM.

Comment: But how does that explain that this behaviour appears when the missing class is *not* the one used as type of the method parameter, but everything works as I would expect when the missing class is *precisely* the one that is used as the type of the method argument?